# full URL path in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, header, http-headers

Is it okay to put full URL path in ajax? I'm having problems accessing the url and I'm getting status 0 for my error response.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://fullurlpath.com/php/myphppagedata.php",
        type: "GET",
        data:  "somedata="+somedata,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    }).error(function(xhr){
             alert(xhr.responseText);
             alert(xhr.status);
    }).done(function(data){
             alert(data);
    });
```

Also, inside my **http://fullurlpath.com/php/myphppagedata.php** I have

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: @Musa, I tried it with relative path, but i'm getting a 404 error, which I'm assuming that its not getting the URL. which is confusing me because I'm having this set of code inside js folder, and the `myphppagedata.php` is in php folder. so I would just do `../php/myphppagedata.php`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm accessing it through a different domain, thats why i'm trying to use full path. But i'm just getting status 0

Comment: also, i'm adding `$.support.cors = true;`

Comment: You can't do Ajax calls to a domain other than origin, the browser blocks those.  There are work-arounds, like jsonp (which jQuery supports).

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/

Comment: @andrewliu what happens when you go to `http://fullurlpath.com/php/myphppagedata.php` in a browser?  The target URL should work just fine whether you use ajax or any other client (a web browser for instance).

Comment: It did work, when I did `http://127.0.0.1/php/myphppagedata.php`. But I accessed this from a different domain. Samething i'm trying to do now, but instead of localhost, I have my files in an actual hosting place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of requesting it with your client's browser using jQuery, I would make a page on your own domain, for instance call it `request.php` with:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://fullurlpath.com/php/myphppagedata.php");
```

This way your server will request the resource, so that you won't have the same origin policy issues. Then ajax this file instead.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "request.php", 
...
```

You can also use `cURL` instead of `file_get_contents()` for more elaborate functionality.

Comment: i would still need to have "http://fullurlpath.com/request.php" because this ajax is being called in a different domain. no?

Comment: No. That's the whole point. `request.php` should be on the same domain as the file that calls ajax.